# How to pass an Empty list as an parameter in Python? Please help me :(

Tags: python, list, arguments, parameter-passing

```
def checkValue(list,n):
    if list.index(n)>=0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

list =[]
n = int(input("Enter range: "))
for i in range(n):
    value = int(input("Enter number: "))
    list.append(value)

a = int(input("Enter checked value: "))
checkValue(list,a)
```

Comment: please do not name variables after builtin types. use `l` instead of `list` - it’s also more concise, if a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Refrain from re-assigning/overwriting builtin keywords such as `list`. this will cause complications down the line unless you know what you're doing. Although this doesn;t seem to be your issue here.

Comment: Please explain further in detail your issue so we can properly help you. Be sure to include full error tracebacks if there are any and/or expected implementation/result

Comment: @rv.kvetch, your advise not to use built-in functions as name is correct, but using single letter `l` is also [not good idea - see PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)

Answer (score 0):

Other than my comment about naming conventions, seems you're forgetting to print your output.

```
print(checkValue(list,a))
```

That is why you're not seeing any result.

Although your code can be cleaned up a bit using the `in` keyword and a simple comprehension to fill the values list as follows:

```
def check_value(l, n):
    return n in l

n = int(input("Enter range: "))
values = [int(input("Enter number: ")) for _ in range(n)]

a = int(input("Enter checked value: "))
print(check_value(values, a))
```

---

```
>>> Enter range: 3
>>> Enter number: 1
>>> Enter number: 2
>>> Enter number: 3
>>> Enter checked value: 2
True
```